Chrome extension manifestV3 DeclarativeNetRequest dynamic query parameters
I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs to redirect all requests to mysite.com to anothersite.com?param1=ts, where ts is the current timestamp hour. While Manifest V2's webRequest API offered a easy solution, I am assuming Manifest V3's declarativeNetRequest sets redirect rule once only. Is it possible to achieve my requirement? What are the options?
Here is the code for v2 using webRequest
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
    let hr = new Date().getHours();
    let redirect_url = `anothersite.com?param1=${hr}`
    return {
        redirectUrl: redirect_url
    };
}, 
{
urls: ["*://mysite.com/*"]
},
["blocking"]
);```


You'll have to update the rule every hour using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules. Use chrome.alarms API and also update the rule in chrome.runtime.onStartup. It won't help with the requests made before the browser initializes your extension though.

@wOxxOm Thanks. I imagined this would be the last thing I would resort to, but don't think there is any other option.
